# Qt - How to get the pointer to base class?

Tags: c++, qt

```
Class B : Class A
{
    void getBasePointer() {
        this->basePointer; //How can I access Class A ? 
    }
}
```

How can I get a pointer to `Class A` in `Class B` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to cast `this` to `A *`, but I see no use in this (unless you have to provide an `A *` to some function, but in that case the cast is implicit); if, instead, the point is that you want to call the base class version of some method, then you have to call `A::methodName()`.